# JSON ARRAY Return 

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-selectors

I have a Array that is pulling back X amount of Data from a JSON file, Lets say 40

I wanted some help where If i want X amount of data from that file, lets say just 20, What't the best approach to do so?

Is there any example out there.

I tried using jQuery.grep function but i was not getting it to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the JSON "file" is a server-side script, then you could add a query string parameter to the request and then change the server-side code to restrict the number of results.

Otherwise, you can simply use the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice) method of `Array` to get a subset of the array of data in your client-side code:

```
var subset = origArray.slice(20);
```

Comment: I'm already getting the data using $.getJSON, i'm already getting all displayed on the page, not i just wanted some of the data, lets say I wanted data number more than 10 out of the entire 40

Comment: The server controls what you get sent, so check if the URL endpoint you're requesting with getJSON has some parameters to control how much data you're getting.